# nginx not passing request to node server, if trailing slash is missing in the url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, proxy

I have setup nginx with wordpress and it is working fine. now i have created a react application, which is running in port 3000. i want my nginx server to pass the request to react server if certain location match.
below is the nginx configuration with wordpress and react app.

```
    listen 80;
    server_name aaroogya.org;
    return 301 https://aaroogya.org$request_uri;
}
server {
#        listen 80;

       
    root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name aaroogya.org www.aaroogya.org;
    #location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        #location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    #server_name testbed2.covidhelp.in;

    location /covidhelp{
#root /var/www/;
#   index index.html;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/ ;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }




     location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }
        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aaroogya.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aaroogya.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

when i visit https://www.aaroogya.org/covidhelp/

it redirect the request to react server but when i tried to load all the static file like bundle.js then it's not working.
for e.g
`https://www.aaroogya.org/covidhelp/static/js/main.chunk.js`    -- not working example
`https://www.aaroogya.org/covidhelp/static/js/main.chunk.js/`   -- added a trailing slash and its working fine.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

**I've resolved the issue with 2 steps.**

1. Check `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```js
connect() failed(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: * .*.*.*, server: * .*.*.*, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "*.*.*.*"
```

Upstream was still `127.0.0.1:8000` even if I set upstream to `127.0.0.1:3000` in nginx conf file.

2. Replace server 127.0.0.1:8000 with server `127.0.0.1:3000` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf` and restart nginx.

Below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Finally, it works with no 502 error.

Comment: its not 502 error, when i run both the server, it fetch index.html from react app but not the static resource file css, js and images.

Comment: @Sudhakar when you open the link which you mentioned, it throws 502 on screen. So probably for this two reason: 1. `NGNIX `, 2. `REACT-ROUTER ` any of the configuration might be wrong.